# JSON not decoding, despite being valid php

Tags: php, json, curl

I've got a json object returning but when I try and decode it it returns the following:

```
{"droplet":{"id":65243848,"name":"blah.com","memory":2048,"vcpus":2,"disk":40,"locked":true,"status":"new","kernel":null,"created_at":"2017-10-06T21:17:30Z","features":[],"backup_ids":[],"next_backup_window":null,"snapshot_ids":[],"image":{"id":28287672,"name":"NGINX-Stack-Blank-10/3/2017","distribution":"Ubuntu","slug":null,"public":false,"regions":["nyc1"],"created_at":"2017-10-03T22:17:46Z","min_disk_size":40,"type":"snapshot","size_gigabytes":2.03},"volume_ids":[],"size":{"slug":"2gb","memory":2048,"vcpus":2,"disk":40,"transfer":3.0,"price_monthly":20.0,"price_hourly":0.02976,"regions":["ams2","ams3","blr1","fra1","lon1","nyc1","nyc2","nyc3","sfo1","sfo2","sgp1","tor1"],"available":true},"size_slug":"2gb","networks":{"v4":[],"v6":[]},"region":{"name":"New York 1","slug":"nyc1","sizes":["512mb","1gb","2gb","c-2","4gb","c-4","8gb","c-8","16gb","m-16gb","c-16","32gb","m-32gb","48gb","c-32","m-64gb","64gb","m-128gb","m-224gb"],"features":["private_networking","backups","ipv6","metadata","install_agent","storage"],"available":true},"tags":[]},"links":{"actions":[{"id":301502253,"rel":"create","href":"https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/actions/301502253"}]}}
```

If I print_r() it and paste it into JSONlint it validates, when I copy\paste the output from print_r() into a string it decodes fine, but when I decode it directly from the CURL response it returns this instead of an array.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'Authorization: Bearer ----',
     'Content-Type: application/json',
     'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    $error = 1;
}
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($output);
print_r($data);
```

This is the code that's returning the above JSON instead of an array.

Comment: In your php backend, you need to perform 2 operations:
1. specify content type: header('content-type: application/json')
2. send the content using json_encode: echo json_encode(your_php_object_or_array)
Are you doing it in this way? (json_encode is optional and you can use echo if you have a valid encoded json string)

Comment: Added the portion of the curl request in question.  It's working on all other calls to their API, it's just this one that's giving me issues and I can't debug it for the life of me.

Comment: You run the response through json_decode and it's still JSON? Maybe the sender double encoded it?

Comment: I'm wondering if there could be some kind of trailing character that I can't see or something, I'm really not sure what the issue could be.  It works fine on every other call to their API.

Comment: 1. `print_r()` lies, use `var_dump()` instead. 2. `var_dump($output, $data);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This mmakes curl return the respnse to your variable, without it then it just prints the result

Comment: Sorry, that's in there too I missed the top part of the curl request as I didn't want to post API data.

Comment: $data = json_decode($output); needs to be $data = json_decode($output, true);

Comment: What do var_dump($output) and var_dump($data) look like?